# Error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to find the digital sum of a number by using loop 
I created a helper function, to make the number into a list. 
however, I keep getting `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['` as the problem.

```
def digital_helper(num):
    a = num
    b = str(a)
    list1 = []
    for digits in b:
        list1.append(int(digits))
    return list1

def digital_sum(num):
    while len(digital_helper(num)) > 1: 
        return digital_sum(digital_helper(sum(digital_helper(num))))
    else:
        return sum(digital_helper(num))
```

The error:

```
>>> digital_sum(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in digital_sum
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in digital_sum
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in digital_helper
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
```

Comment: And what is `num` then? You have a value with `[` in it, that is not a number.

Comment: is `num` in `digital_helper` a list? If so, `str(listvalue)` will result in a string with square brackets.

Comment: that's a number, but digital_helper produces a list

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: that makes sense. i am going to revise that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the ball closely:

1. `num` initially is an integer.
2. `digital_helper()` however, returns a list, which you then pass to `digital_sum()` again:

   ```
   return digital_sum(digital_helper(...))
   ```
3. In that recursive call in `digital_sum()`, `num` is now a list.
4. You then pass `num` to `digital_helper()` again, but now it is a list, and the code fails.

The code fails because a list of numbers, like `[1, 2, 3]` turned into a string includes the character `'['`, and that is not an integer.